# How to mutate an incoming string in an observableField

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have the following field binded to an editText.

```
val lastName = ObservableField(MutableLiveData<String>())
```

I want to mutate the entered string so that the first letter will be automatically set in uppercase.

So if you type

```
williams -> Williams
```

I thought I could solve this by doing this as follows

```
    lastName.getObservable()
        .subscribe { input ->
            val lastname = input.decapitalize()
            lastName.getField().postValue(lastname.capitalize())
        }
```

I noticed that doing it this way, will throw me in an eternal loop because of the postvalue triggering the subscribe each time. How can I mutate the incoming string through RxJava without having to do it in the way I have it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at the source by overriding `set`. I don't see the reason for multi-layered observability, so I flattened it here.

```
val lastName = object: ObservableField<String>() {
        override fun set(value: String) {
            super.set(value.capitalize())
        }
    }
```

If there is some reason you need the layering, you could instead override the `setValue` method of the MutableLiveData.

```
val lastName = ObservableField(object: MutableLiveData<String>() {
        override fun setValue(value: String) {
            super.setValue(value.capitalize())
        }
    })
```

But this multi-layering looks convoluted to me. I don't see how you can reliably subscribe to the underlying data if the LiveData instance can be overwritten.